# Proposition about Euclidean distance

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

About Euclidean space ($n$-dimensional)

$d^n(x,y)$ is Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$. For any $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$

$B(a,r):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : d^n(a,x)<r\}.$

Proposition ;

If there exists $R>0$ such that $B(b,R)\cap B(a,r)=\emptyset$ then $d(a,b)\ge r+R$ holds.

I thought that triangle inequality may be useful, but if I use triangle inequality, $d(a,b)\le\dots$ the direction of inequality sign is contrary.

How can I prove this proposition?

Comment: As a start, draw a picture to get intuition.

Comment: Yes. As a start, I drawn a picture(2-dimentional), and I found that d(a,b)≧r+R holds. However, I couldn't prove this proposition by using formula.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider $x=a+(b-a) (\frac r {d(a,b)}-\frac  1 n) $. Verify that t$x \in B(a,r)$. Hence $x \notin B(b,R)$. So $\|x-b\| \geq R$. This is true for each $n$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\|(a-b)+(b-a) (\frac r {d(a,b)}\| \geq R$. This gives $d(a,b) \geq r+R$. [Note that $d(a,b) \geq r$ since $b \notin B(a,r)$].